# Not able to change right navigation button title

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I set up a right navigation button like so in`viewWillAppear` in . a class `ChatMessageViewController`..

```
let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: nil, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(blockPressed(sender:)))
button2.title = "Block"
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button2
```

Now on the click of `blockPressed` another shared function is called like so...

```
@objc fileprivate func blockPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    XMPPConfig.shared.blockUser(userJID: theUserJID!) //XMPPConfig is another class having some common functions and delegate methods.

  }
```

(This function basically blocks a certain user like blocking a whatsapp user. Once blocking happens, certain delegate methods are called. One such delegate method after which I change the `Block` button is given as follows..)

```
func xmppBlocking(_ sender: XMPPBlocking!, didBlockJID xmppJID: XMPPJID!) {
    print("successfully blocked!")

    ChatMessageViewController.shared.setupUnBlock()

  }
```

Doing this also properly calls `setupUnBlock()` function in `ChatMessageViewController` like so...

```
func setupUnBlock() {

    if XMPPConfig.shared.sectionGroupsFlag == false {
      let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: nil, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unblockPressed(sender:)))
      button2.title = "Unblock"
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button2
    }
  }
```

But the button title still remains unchanged...i.e. it is still "Block"..what could be the reason for this...?

Comment: did you use breakpoints?

Comment: yes...still clueless..:(

Comment: did app goes to that if block? navigationItem != nil?

Comment: there doesn't seem . to be such a condition as `navigationItem != nil`

Comment: @user308123, Try to change `UIBarButtonItem` `tintColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `UINavigationBarButton` using another initializer:

```
let right = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Some title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightNavBarButtonPressed))
```

You are using `UIBarButtonItem(image:...` instead.

Comment: Then put a breakpoint to the line `let button2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: nil, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(unblockPressed(sender:)))` and check, if it's executed. If no, check the result of the condition `if XMPPConfig.shared.sectionGroupsFlag == false` and check if `navigationItem == nil`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate your code and apparently everything works.

So, the problem may be due to three possible problems, as far as i can see.

1. it may be thread problem. This is unlikley unless you have not turned on the thread checker in xcode.. But inside both unblock and block codes, enter

   print(Thread.current)
   to see both blocks of codes in setting the rightbarButton is in main thread. If not, you should know how to solve them.
2. It may be view update problem, unlikely still, but worth a try.. So in your block of codes where you are adding rightBarButton, add one more line of code.

   self.navigationController?.viewIfLoaded?.setNeedsLayout()

to update the navigationController's view after you have set the rightBarButtonItem.

3. The most likely problem in my opinion is that, you have been doubling calling block barButtonItem codes. This means when you have called unblock barButtonItem setup codes, you accidentally called the block barButtonItem too.

To debug this is easy, you just put a statement in each of block of the codes, to see if they appear together.